# Scroll one page instead of jumping to the current pointer position

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, arm

I changed these settings in **about:config** of firefox (ubuntu) to get the scrolling work like other browsers for e.g. Chrome (windows) or chromium (Ubuntu)

```
widget.gtk.overlay-scrollbars.enabled false 
widget.non-native-theme.gtk.scrollbar.thumb-size 1
widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar.size.override 15

general.smoothScroll true
general.smoothScroll.stopDecelerationWeighting 0.8
mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount 60
layout.frame_rate.precise true
mousewheel.acceleration.start 1
mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount 60
____
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMaxMS: 250
general.smoothScroll.currentVelocityWeighting: 0
mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount: 25
```

But when I click at the bottom of the screen, it scrolls to the end instead of page down.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the value of "general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMaxMS" to something higher than 250, like 500.

This value represents the maximum duration of the scroll animation in milliseconds.

```
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMaxMS: 500
```

Comment: Still not expected scrolling. First of all the scroll-bar is hidden unnecessarily and even if I manage to un-hide it, there is no way to "Page Down" using a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this duplicate configuration?

```
mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount 60
mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount: 25
```

If you want to perform a page down action instead of scrolling to the end, you should try reducing that value.

- **mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount:** This setting determines the minimum distance a mousewheel scroll action must move to be interpreted as a "line scroll." In this case, it's set to "60" units. A larger value means you need to scroll more for each "line" of content."

Comment: Tried this option. The scrolling is still not similar to page down.